# adding signature in a pdf file

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding a digital signature to a pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107138/adding-a-digital-signature-to-a-pdf-file)

1). user will upload a pdf file
2). and then will upload his signatures
3). embed the signature in pdf file

Comment: And what is your question? As in : what did you try, where do you have a problem with?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a PDF editing library. I've used PDFSharp in the past and it works well.
http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/